# C++ compiler complaining about no default constructor

Tags: c++, oop, object, constructor

Given this struct with a private stateful variable:

```
struct Calibrate
{
private:
    Stitcher stitcher_obj_;

}
```

This is the stitcher object (with empty constructor):

```
Stitcher::Stitcher(const std::vector<cv::Mat> &src_images){}
```

When calling `Calibrate`, I am getting this error:

```
default constructor of 'Calibrate' is implicitly deleted because field 'stitcher_obj_' has no default constructor
Stitcher stitcher_obj_
         ^
```

Thanks for any suggestions on how to fix this!

Comment: Provide a default constructor for `Stitcher`.

Comment: @cigien I do have a constructor for `Stitcher`, I was confused by the wording?

Comment: A default constructor is one that accepts NO parameters, not an "empty constructor" (to use your description for a constructor with a body which does nothing).   By providing a constructor that accepts an argument, you have required that the compiler not generate a default constructor by default.   If you need a default constructor, you need to either define one or force the compiler to define one  (e.g. from C++11, in `Stitcher` have a `Stitcher() = default`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you provide a custom constructor for a class, the default constructor (the 0 argument constructor) is no longer synthesized. You need to reinstate it manually, like this:

```
class Stitcher {
  Stitcher() = default;
  // ...
};
```